# 6 percent of what number would be 3

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

I have a question about percent calculation, I don't know the number.

6 percent of what number would be 3?

Can anyone answer the question with detail?

Comment: $\frac{3}{6}*100 = 50$

Comment: Hi can you add an answer and some detail how It comes 50? :)

Comment: If you call the unknown number $x$, you can say $0.06 x = 3$ from which you conclude $x = \frac{3}{0.06}$.

Comment: If 6% is 3, then how much is 1%? That's one-sixth of 3, or 0.5, right? Now if 1% is 0.5, how much is 100%?

Comment: @bof If $6\%$ is $3$, then $2\%$ is $1$, so $100\%$ is ... avoiding fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start by thinking about what a percent actually is. Percent can be split in to two words: per meaning, well per, and cent meaning 100. So when you read percent, you should be thinking: per 100. So 6%= 6 per 100.

Now we've got another mathematical notation for that. $\frac{1}{100}$ also means 1 per 100. So when we say 6%, what we really mean is $6*\frac{1}{100}$ or $\frac{6}{100}$.

Since we know that the 6 percent of something (which we'll call $n$ for "number" so that we can keep things short) equals 3, we know that $\frac{6}{100}*n=3$. Then all we need to do is some algebraic rearranging to solve for our number $n$. Let's start by multiplying both sides by 100. Then $6*n=300$. Can you figure out what $n$ must be from here?

If you can't, here's another hint, though I strongly encourage you to try to solve the above problem first.

> How about we try divide both sides by 6? Does that give us anything useful?

Comment: great answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Solve the equation used to calculate percentages:

$$\frac6{100}x=3$$

Comment: please tell me what is x?

Comment: The number you want! To calculate $\;r\%\;$ of a quantity $\;x\;$ one must do $\;\frac r{100}x\;$ . In you case you know the outcome must be $\;3\;$ and you already know $\;r=6\;$ .